# How to manage mongodb hierarchy for better searching and support new queries

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, hierarchy

I have some hierarchy like below

[image]

I am storing in mongodb like below

```
db.categories.insert( { _id: "College", parent: null } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "EC", parent: "College" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "CSE", parent: "College" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "CIVIL", parent: "College" } )

db.categories.insert( { _id: "B1", parent: "EC" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "B3", parent: "EC" } )

db.categories.insert( { _id: "R1", parent: "B1" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "R2", parent: "B1" } )

db.categories.insert( { _id: "R5", parent: "B3" } )
db.categories.insert( { _id: "R6", parent: "B3" } )
```

But I am not able find queries to do the below operation .

1. Check for any child and parent valid combination example  R1 and EC is valid,  R6 and  EC  is  not valid ?
2. Delete B1 and make the child point to its parent? R1 and R2 become direct children of EC after B1 deletes
3. Delete all the child after B1 including B1?
4. Will these queries take more time as number of children increases, like 1000 or 100000?

I went through [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-parent-references/) but not able find  queries to solve my search looking for.

Comment: See if this has anything useful: [Model Tree Structures](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/).

Comment: I went though that but it is not solving the queries I am looking for.